# Exchange 2010 SPAM filter

Tags: exchange-2010, spam

We have Exchange 2010 with the built in SPAM filter installed.  Was wondering if there is a way to check what messages have been blocked.  We have a customer trying to send an e-mail and it never shows up.  I suspect that the customer may have been black-listed by SPAM-COP.  Also, is there any way to allow mail from the customer's domain to get through the Exchange 2010 spam filter.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0):

To check the Exchange Antispam Agent logs for emails from a specific sender:

```
Get-AgentLog -StartDate "1/1/2014" | where {$_.P1FromAddress -like "john@doe.com"}
```

Replace the date with the date that you want to search on and replace the email address with the email address of the sender that you want to search for.

---

To whitelist a single email address:

```
$list = (Get-ContentFilterConfig).BypassedSenders
$list.add("john@doe.com")`
Set-ContentFilterConfig -BypassedSenders $list
```

---

To whitelist an entire domain:

```
$list = (Get-ContentFilterConfig).BypassedSenderDomains
$list.add("doe.com")
Set-ContentFilterConfig -BypassedSenderDomains $list
```

---

To check what's currently whitelisted:

```
Get-ContentFilterConfig
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, very much appreciated